# How do I find an item by value in an combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, find, items

In C#, I have variable, `a`, of type `string`.

How do I `find item` by value of `a` in `combobox` (I want find item with value no display text of combobox).

Comment: Please show how the combobox is filled.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which UI toolkit you are using.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can find it by using the following code.

```
int index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(a);
```

To get the item itself, write:

```
comboBox1.Items[index];
```

Comment: will it work in databound combobox also?

Answer (score 17):

You should see a method on the combo box control for FindStringExact(), which will search the displaymember and return the index of that item if found.  If not found will return -1.

```
//to select the item if found: 
mycombobox.SelectedIndex = mycombobox.FindStringExact("Combo"); 

//to test if the item exists: 
int i = mycombobox.FindStringExact("Combo"); 
if(i >= 0)
{
  //exists
}
```

Comment: I think FindExactString() works on the DisplayMember property of the ComboBox. I think the question is asking about how to match on the ValueMember property of a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I know my solution is very simple and funny, but before I train I used it. Important: DropDownStyle of combobox must be "DropDownList"!

First in combobox and then:

```
bool foundit = false;
String mystr = "item_1";
mycombobox.Text = mystr;
if (mycombobox.SelectedText == mystr) // Or using mycombobox.Text
    foundit = true;
else foundit = false;
```

It works for me right and resolved my problem...
But the way (solution) from @st-mnmn is better and fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys the best way if searching for a text or value is

```
int Selected = -1;    
int count = ComboBox1.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; (i<= (count - 1)); i++) 
     {        
         ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
        if ((string)(ComboBox1.SelectedValue) == "SearchValue") 
        {
            Selected = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Selected;
```

Comment: Use "if ((string) (ComboBox1.Items[i]) ==  "SearchValue")" instead of "ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
        if ((string)(ComboBox1.SelectedValue) == "SearchValue")"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for VB.NET code, please convert it to c#.

I prepared the following function bcoz of .NET 3.5 Windows Application:

```
Public Function FindIndex_by_value(ByRef combo As ComboBox, ByVal value As String) As Integer

Dim idx As Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To combo.Items.Count - 1
  Dim itm As DataRowView

  itm = combo.Items(i)
  Dim vl As String = itm.Item(0) 
  If vl = value Then
    idx = i
    Exit For
  End If
Next

Return idx
  End Function
```

using this function:

```
Dim idx As Integer = FindIndex_by_value(comboBox1, "Value_to_Search")
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = idx
```

Important:
here 0 is index of the value column and I used the first column as value column in my DB query.