# Set Combobox selected item based on its ItemsValue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a Combobox, in which let's say that an item's Display Text is "School" and  it's Item Value is 19. So i have stored this 19 into a DataGrid.

Then, i retrieve Combobox Value from DataGrid, then what i want to do is simply that based on value retrieved from DataGrid, combobox should set it's display Item or SelectedItem which have Value 19. In above scenario Combobox should display its selected item "School" if its value was 19.

So far i have wrote code upto this point. But it always giving me First Item of a Combobx.

```
            DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if(rowSelected!=null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count;i++ )
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue) == Convert.ToString(rowSelected[14]))
                {
                    index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
                }
                comboBox1.SelectedItem= comboBox1.Items[index];
            }
            textBox9.Text=rowSelected[14].ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find an item by value in an combobox in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160708/how-do-i-find-an-item-by-value-in-an-combobox-in-c)

Comment: When i wrote this comboBox1.Items[index]; this thing gave me error which is this only assignment, call, increment, decrement , expression can be used as a statement.

Comment: It is to get the item at that place  Not to set the item

Comment: It is working now but it is always returning me 1st Item of Combobox. I have edited my code in question please have a look on it.

Comment: I dont see any edit

Comment: Kindly Check it now

Comment: question why are looping over the combobox items?

Comment: Because to search for Item for which value matches so that can get this item

Comment: Basically i want to get item in Combobox whose value matches with the items in combobox

Comment: see you're using `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` so there is no need to loop over all of them

Comment: but it is giving me first value each time. My problem is not being resolved

Comment: can you tell me how to search for item with matching value ?

Comment: Thanks i have solved m Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
if(rowSelected!=null)
{
    int index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(rowSelected[14]);
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[index];
}
```

or

> Use [`FindStringExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method of  combobox

```
int i = comboBox1.FindStringExact("Combo"); 
if(i >= 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i am able to retrieve the Combobox Item, Based on its value which i am retrieving from the WPF DataGrid.

```
            for (int i = 0;i <comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
                if ((string)(comboBox1.SelectedValue) == Convert.ToString(rowSelected[14]))
                {
                    index = i;
                }

            }

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
```